# Swift: Is there a maximum timer speed?

Tags: swift, timer

For my question, I am referencing `Timer` in Swift, from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer):

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval ti: TimeInterval, 
                     target aTarget: Any, 
                     selector aSelector: Selector, 
                     userInfo: Any?, 
                     repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> Timer
```

My question is about the `timeInterval` parameter: Is there a decimal value greater than 0 where the timer speed would remain constant? I am asking because after doing some tests, using an interval of `0.00001` and `0.00000001` did not seem to produce any noticeable differences. I did not come across an answer in the documentation nor in Google reasearch.

Comment: 0.00000001 is 0.01 microseconds or 10 nanoseconds. A typical mid range processor these day would clock in about 3.5 GHz, which one clock pulse every 0.286 nano seconds. For a timer to work down to that speed, one in every ~35 clock ticks needs to be the timer firing. That's... no where close to possible. What use case do you have that could even benefit from something like this?

Comment: @Alexander It's just that I was using a timer for a simple animation, and I realized that I could make the movement larger instead of making the timer speed faster.

Comment: Indeed. And given that displays only refresh at 30, 60 or tops 120 FPS, there's no point updating your animation any faster than that. `CADisplayLink` seems perfect for your use case.

Comment: @Alexander Got it, thank you so much!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2806814-maximumframespersecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, an NSTimer is called in the runloop of the main thread, and thus the maximum rate at which it can reliably be called is usually between 30 to 60 times per second (perhaps up to 120 times per second on a newer iPad Pro), related to the display frame rate.  Thus, the shortest reliable time interval is usually in the range of 8 to 33.3 milliseconds.  Certainly not 10 uS.

A more reliable timer is to use CADisplayLink, which is usually locked to the display frame rate of 60 frames per second more reliably than an NSTimer, which seems to have lower priority, thus greater latency or fire-time jitter.  For finer timing resolution, you might try using a GCD dispatch timer, which supports a leeway parameter, in a dedicated thread, or even sit in a spin loop polling a mach timer.

Comment: Here is a nice blog article on iOS timer experiments: http://atastypixel.com/blog/experiments-with-precise-timing-in-ios/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm more of a beginner with timers, but aren't `NSTimer` and `Timer` two different things?

Comment: Timer is the new Swift 5 name for the same Foundation class as NSTimer in Objective C.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Timer is the Swift 3 (not 5) name for NSTimer.